# Combining text and circular background marker with ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology

I see that it is possible to create a circular symbol (among other shapes) with [SimpleMarkerSymbol](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm#jsapi/simplemarkersymbol.htm).

I also see that it is possible to create a text symbol with [TextSymbol](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm#jsapi/textsymbol.htm).

Is it possible to combine these two to put a bit of text, centered, over the top of a circle element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest method is going to be to use two graphics layers with two different symbologies. (Or, if you have a large number of symbols and access to arcgis server, use a map service with the correct symbology underneath a graphics layer with blank symbols with no fill; that's what I do here: http://maps.stlouisco.com/police/beta)

It should be feasible to create a symbol class that does what you want. I want to do that for my application, so I will try to take some time later this week to figure that out.

Comment: Is there any documentation available on creating custom symbol classes?

Comment: Not that I could find. It is going to take diving into the code base to figure out.

Comment: I have the same problem as jsight, please, blord-castillo, could you extend your explanation about how to proceed? I am not sure of understanding what you say: I can publish my symbology in ArcGIS Server, but then, how do I use it on my ArcGIS JS side? How to associate to the textSymbol the symbology in my server? Thanks.

Comment: I am working on changing this process, but what I am doing in that sample is publishing a map service and using that to display the symbols on the map. Meanwhile, on top of the map service, is a separate graphics layers using data from the map service (I will change this to feature service in the feature) to create a graphics layer on top of the symbols. The graphics layer uses a blank symbology; but allows on click and mouse over interactions still

Answer (score 0):

There has been a lot of advances in ArcGIS JavaScript now SDK 4.x.  You can do this now with only one graphic per point.  Then you can add text to the point using LabelingInfo.  Here is an example using ArcGIS JavaScript SDK 4.x with a simple marker and text centered in the simple marker:

First, you have your simple marker renderer:

```
let mySymbol = {
  type: "simple-marker",  
  style: "circle",
  color: "blue",
  size: "20",
  outline: {  
    color: [ 255, 255, 0 ],
    width: 2  
  }
};
```

Then, you create your labelinginfo object that will hold your text based on the desired field.  In this case CustomerNumber:

```
var labelingInfo = [
        {
            labelExpression: "[CustomerNumber]",
            labelPlacement: "center-center",
            symbol: {
                type: "text",
                color: "white",
                font: {
                    family: "Arial",
                    size: 12,
                    weight: "bold",
                    decoration: "none"
                }
            }
        }
    ];
```

Finally, you tie in the marker and text together using the feature layer object:

```
const myLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        title: "My Layer",
        fields: myFields,
        objectIdField: "ObjectID",
        geometryType: "point",
        source: YOUR_SOURCE_HERE,
        renderer: mySymbol,
        showLabels: true,
        labelingInfo: labelingInfo
    });
```